# Arranging multiple "boxes" with Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, grid

I have in mind a container (Box "1") that will contain two equal boxes (Box "A" & Box "B") in a horizontal grid.
Each of Box "A" and Box "B" will contain three boxes (Box "2", Box "3", Box "4")  and
(Box "5", Box "6", Box "7) again in a horizontal grid.
(Hopefully, the image supplied is visiable)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oERNp.png)

The thing is, I don't understand the <class="row g-3> and <class="col=md-6"> rules at all. I've used so many different combinations my wife thinks she's a widow.

Can someone help me sort this out?

Many Thanks
-Paul-

Answer (score 0):

Each `row` has 12 columns. To specify the size of a child, use the class `col-` followed by the number of columns. The `-md-` that is sometimes in the class name is for the screen size (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/). And each `row` has to be in a `container`.

```css
.col-4 {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="border:2px solid red">
    <div class="col-6 container" style="border:2px solid blue">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Box2</div>
        <div class="col-4">Box3</div>
        <div class="col-4">Box4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 container" style="border:2px solid blue">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Box5</div>
        <div class="col-4">Box6</div>
        <div class="col-4">Box7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```